# Using BubbleWrap to read JSON files

Tags: json, rubymotion

I have a backend to an IOS application. I am trying to read the data from my rails backend by using JSON. My bubbleWrap get request is as follows.

```
BW::HTTP.get("url_here/children/1.json") do |response|
   json = BW::JSON.parse response.body.to_str
   for line in json
     p line[:name]
   end
end
```

It doesn't bring any data back, it actually breaks my code. I can't find any documentation with an example of how to use REST from rubymotion/Bubblewrap and pull data back to my application.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the errors that you get? A problem could be `BW:HTTP.jet` (should be `BW:HTTP.get`).

Comment: Apologies Riccardo, I have changed it. It is .get in my code. That was a typo on the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always check the response code before parsing the response body. You might

```
BW::HTTP.get(url) do |response|
  if response.ok?
    data = BW::JSON.parse(response.body.to_str)
    # make sure you have an array or hash before you try iterating over it
    data.each {|item| p item}
  else
    warn "Trouble"
  end
end
```

Also make sure you sanity-check the JSON response vs your code's expectation. Perhaps the JSON is an array and not a hash?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a handy class abstraction that I use in a lot of my applications... it completely abstracts the API call logic from the view controller logic for separation of concerns and is heavily modeled after [Matt Green's](http://vimeo.com/groups/199097/videos/69529067) [Inspect 2013](http://vimeo.com/groups/199097) talk.

```
class MyAPI

  APIURL = "http://your.api.com/whatever.json?date="

  def self.dataForDate(date, &block)
    BW::HTTP.get(APIURL + date) do |response|
        json = nil
        error = nil

        if response.ok?
          json = BW::JSON.parse(response.body.to_str)
        else
          error = response.error_message
        end

        block.call json, error
    end
  end

end
```

Then to call this class we do:

```
MyAPI.dataForDate(dateString) do |json, error|
  if error.nil?
      if json.count > 0
        json.each do |cd|
          # Whatever with the data
        end
      else
        App.alert("No Results.")
      end
  else
    App.alert("There was an error downloading data from the server. Please check your internet connection or try again later.")
  end
end
```